# Empty Grid Cells Until Resize

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJS 7.3.1 and I have a grid bound to a virtual store with a REST proxy. Cell values are mapped to properties of the models loaded into the store. Nothing really special here AFAIK.

I find that when I load the view, it's pulling data from the API and adding rows to the grid as expected but the cells are empty. However, when I resize the window and thus the grid, the cells are then populated correctly.

Looking in the browser's devtools before the resize, I see the cell looks like below where the content of its `x-body-el` is `&nbsp;` instead of the value from the model's property.

```
<div data-componentid="ext-gridcell-10" class="x-gridcell x-widthed x-align-left" data-xid="101" id="ext-gridcell-10" tabindex="-1" style="width: 473.688px;">
  <div data-qoverflow="true" class="x-body-el x-gridcell-body-el" id="ext-element-326">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

After the resize, the `&nbsp;` is replaced by the correct value from the model.

Really odd. A bug perhaps?

Comment: Could you please share a Sencha fiddle showing your problem? (https://fiddle.sencha.com)

Comment: Sorry but I've been unable to reproduce the issue with a fiddle. I've been discussing this with support and we've found the issue goes away if I use a normal store instead of a virtual one. Still digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ExtJS 7.3 unfortunately some bugs were added regarding the virtual store. I also created a ticket for such a problem, which is caused by executing reload. Here not only the cells are empty, the selection model is also broken.

I created a fiddle for this (possibly it's the same problem):
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3c0u

If you click on 'load' everything works fine.
If you click on 'load and reload' you will get empty cells.
Same for clicking on 'reload'

Hint: You have to re-run the application in order to see the problem. If a load happens at first, it will work and you cannot reproduce the problem.

We solved this temporary by adding the following override:

```
Ext.define('X.override.data.virtual.Store', {
    override: 'Ext.data.virtual.Store',

    privates: {
        handleReload: function (op) {
            var me = this,
                activeRanges = me.activeRanges,
                len = activeRanges.length,
                pageMap = me.pageMap,
                resultSet = op.getResultSet(),
                wasSuccessful = op.wasSuccessful(),
                pageNumber = op.config && op.config.page,
                rsRecords = [],
                i, range, page;

            if (wasSuccessful) {
                me.readTotalCount(resultSet);

                // Condition for a valid page
                if (me.pageMap.getPageCount() !== 0 && pageNumber) {
                    page = me.pageMap.getPage(pageNumber - 1, false);

                    if (page && !(page.error = op.getError())) {
                        // Filling the page with records loaded from the operation
                        // and marking the page as loaded
                        page.records = op.getRecords();
                        page.state = 'loaded';
                    }
                }

                me.fireEvent('reload', me, op);

                for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                    range = activeRanges[i];

                    if (pageMap.canSatisfy(range)) {
                         range.reload();
                    }
                }
                // override start

                // This fixes the problem, that first page entries are displayed as empty rows
                // and the selection model not working after reload.
                // With this override, the page will be handled like in a load.
                // This is only called for the active page, since the others are loaded normally over load.
                // Has to be placed after range.reload(). Otherwise the selection will break (only works if both exist).
                // Issue EXTJS-29428
                if (pageMap && page) {
                    pageMap.onPageLoad(page);
                }
                // override end
            }

            if (resultSet) {
                rsRecords = resultSet.records;
            }

            me.fireEvent('load', me, rsRecords, wasSuccessful, op);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The initial symptom is the same, "empty" cells, so it may be related but my trouble is a little different. The empty cells get populated property when the grid is resized horizontally. Subsequent reloads don't result in the fault unless the entire page is reloaded. Also, if the number of rows in the table exceeds the number that will fit without scrolling then the issue doesn't crop up though I system this is because the grid is resized horizontally when the scrollbar is added.

Comment: Okay. But we faced multiple problems with the virtual store and some of the problems came with 7.3. So possibly you can try whether the problem occurs also in 7.2.
I think for further help a fiddle is needed.

Comment: Understood and agreed. Much thanks for the input.

Comment: Was never able to reproduce this with a fiddle but Sencha Support offered that same overload to test and it does in fact resolve the issue. I still don't understand why but I'm moving on. Thanks much Timz.

Comment: So they share our override? Nice :-) As a hint: Because of additional problems which came with 7.3.X, we decided to use the implementation of 7.2 for virtual stores. 
## Selection broken: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3cgm&view/editor
##  Wrong records for filtering: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ccn&view/editor
## Wrong records for filtering2: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cmt .
We created tickets for all of those problems, but without any result yet.

If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: They sent me the same override you posted, like, verbatim. I should never have doubted you ;). Still don't understand why it's working now.